# lilypond: can I combine \autochange and \change Staff?

Tags: lilypond

With a PianoStaff, and having all the melody in the upper staff, if we put `\autochange` before the melody, the notes will be displayed in the upper or the lower staff depending on their height. I would like to be able to interrupt briefly this behaviour, for a couple of notes that I want to set explicitly into some staff. I was thinking of using `\change Staff = "down"` but this does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Well, an `\autochange` plays its contents in a sandbox in order to calculate the change requests, then does it "for real".  But the sandbox does not actually have the staves where a `\change` could have an effect.

So you need to put the `\change` in the "for real part", and provide a `\context Voice` where you'll be able to capture the autochange voice produced during the "for real" phase.  This could look like

```
<<
  \context Staff = "up"
  <<
    \autochange { g4 c' e' g c' e' g c' e' }
    \context Voice { s1 \change Staff = "up" }
  >>
  \context Staff = "down" { \clef bass s1*4 }
>>
```

Comment: For the next wayfairing stranger, `autochange` has been renamed to `autoChange`.